# Bash: read date by specific format

Tags: bash, date

I'am trying to read date in bash by known format:

```
date -d '2009/05/11 08:27:00'
```

works perfectly, it detect format and read it correctly, but it dont work for next case (or something like this):

```
date -d '[2009/05/11 08:27:00]'
```

I know format before reading, can I force date to read by known format (in this case) `[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]`  like I'm doing it on print

```
date +'[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU `date` is very flexible about the form argument to `-d` but even its flexibility has limits.  You will need to remove the square brackets.  With `bash`:

```
date -d "$(sed 's/[][]//g' <<<'[2009/05/11 08:27:00]')"
```

Or, with a POSIX shell:

```
date -d "$(echo '[2009/05/11 08:27:00]' | sed 's/[][]//g')"
```

#### Another example

This format was suggested in the comments:

```
$ date  -d '2009.05.11 07:30:00'
date: invalid date ‘2009.05.11 07:30:00’
```

Again, that is a format that `date` does not understand.  It has be changed to something that `date` does understand:

```
$ date  -d "$(sed 's|[.]|/|g' <<<'2009.05.11 07:30:00')"  # (bash)
Mon May 11 07:30:00 PDT 2009
```

Comment: It can be any format. for examle  date fail with -d'2009.05.11 07:30:00' but I know format before reading. script should be able read format as argument, and work with data

Comment: @Dmitriy That is correct: you have to give `date -d` a format that `date` understands.  Just because you can understand the format does not mean that `date` understands it.